# Python print dictionary in order

Tags: python

Hello i want to print this dictionary in order but i dont know how:

```
s = input("")
slist = s.split()
finaldict = {}
for word in slist:
    if not finaldict.get(word):
        finaldict[word] = slist.count(word)

for palabra in finaldict:
    finaldict[palabra]=str(finaldict[palabra])
    print(palabra,finaldict[palabra])
```

input : `this is a test a test a test`
expected output:

```
this 1
is 1
a 3
test 3
```

i want that order but i get random order prints

Thanks!

Comment: In *what* order?

Comment: Alphabetical order? Order in which items added?

Comment: @user2357112 I think he means the order of __first occurrence__ of the words.

Comment: I want to keep the order of the input

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared

Comment: @Shiva yes i want to keep the first ocurrence of the words

Comment: from collections import OrderedDict

Comment: Solved thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really have an order in a dictionary. Look at the OrderedDict module to print things in the order you store them

```
import collections 
s = input("")
slist = s.split()
finaldict = collections.OrderedDict()
for word in slist:
    if not finaldict.get(word):
        finaldict[word] = slist.count(word)

for palabra in finaldict:
    finaldict[palabra]=str(finaldict[palabra])
    print(palabra,finaldict[palabra])
```

Comment: It worked thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Remember to accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries by their nature are unordered. You want to use an `OrderedDict` (found in the `collections` module). You would assign to an `OrderedDict` in the same way you would a regular `dict`, and initialize it by passing a list of 2-tuples to the `OrderedDict` constructor. For example:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> spam = OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])
>>> spam['c'] = 3
>>> print spam
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
>>> eggs = OrderedDict()
>>> eggs['a'] = 1
>>> print eggs
OrderedDict([('a', 1)])
```